# XML document not validating against XSD schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xml-validation

I have the below XML Schema:

```
         <xs:element name="_links">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="self">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="href" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="next">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="href" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="prev">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="href" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

A specific XML document I am validating does not have a "next" field in it (although some documents can).  When I load this document I am receiving the error:

```
Error validating source XML against schema - The element '_links' in namespace 'http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon' has invalid child element 'prev' in namespace 'http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon'. List of possible elements expected: 'next' in namespace 'http://www.orbis-software.com/WebSvcCon'.
```

As per the XSD the "next" element is set to minOccurs=0 making it optional, so why I am receiving the error?

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete XSD that tried to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

In your schema the contents of the `_links` elements is defined in

```
    <xs:element name="_links">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="self">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="href" type="xs:string" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="next">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="href" type="xs:string" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="prev">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="href" type="xs:string" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

as a sequence of three elements, namely `self`, `next` and `prev`. None of these elements is optional as none of them has a `mixOccurs="0"`, there is only a `mixOccurs="0"` on the content of each of those elements as they can can contain 0 to unbounded `href` elements.

So `<_links><self/><next/><prev/></_links>` is possible but you can't leave out any of those three elements.

Comment: More specifically, the `href` element is optional, so the `next` element can be empty, but the `next` element isn't optional so it must be present.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I got this working by specifying the min occurs twice:

```
        <xs:element name="_links">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="self">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="href" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="next">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="href" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="prev">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="href" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```